# How to get Tensorflow estimator model_fn inputs shape?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I want to use the tensorflow estimator to build a stacked autoencoder, and i use input_fn to batch input the model. But i don't know how to get the dynamic shape to set the weight.

The code example like this:

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):   
    W_init = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer()
    w = tf.get_Variable(shape= ???, initializer=W_init  )
    ...
```